# Querying with Eloquent - Achieve Join

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

How to select records from db from a situation like below using eloquent

Tables:

Employee Table  [ id,name]

Address Table   [id,address_line1,employee_id,city_id]

City Table      [id,name]

A Query like below does only return city id, but i need the city name as well

```
$employee = Employee::with('address')->get();
```

And My Employee Model have relationship as

```
public function address(){
$this->hasMany('address');
}
```

How to achieve the desired result so that the output of the query should give me city name from city table, based on the id from address table, without running new query for each city id to get names

Comment: Almost there. check out the one-to-many relationship in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many . The `with()` function let's you eager load this relationship. This way you would only use two queries to get every `employee` alongside with their `address`.

Comment: yup
tried that, but how to get city name as city id is in address table ??

Comment: So then you'd have to use three queries in total. Build another relationship between `address` and `city`. Then retrieve the city name: `$employee->address->city->name`

Comment: Interesting.. I'll try that now

Comment: Cool, Eloquent is pretty awesome :)